# Running ADB Shell commands rapidly in C# console app

Tags: c#, shell, adb

I'm trying to run a rapid amount of adb shell commands. Basically, i want to start adb shell, and then run a bunch of commands in rapid succession. Can I reuse a Process in some way? I'd like to just start adb shell and change the command text at runtime.

The problem is with creating a separate process for each command spins up a lot of process and eventually adb craps out on me.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string AdbBroadcast = "shell am broadcast <my_cmd>";


        int broacastIndex = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Outputting " + broacastIndex);

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "adb";
            startInfo.Arguments = AdbBroadcast;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            process.WaitForExit();


            Thread.Sleep(250);
            broacastIndex++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help with your specific error, but you should call .Dispose on your process when you are finished with it (after 'WaitForExit').  If this loop has a lot of iterations you might be running out of process handles at the OS level.  Disposing of the process should release the handle so that it can be reused.

Answer (score -1):

When a device does not respond to shell commands issued via adb via Process, you can check the device state like follows:

```
    ProcessStartInfo lcmdInfo1;

    lcmdInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo(" adb.exe ", "get-state");
    lcmdInfo1.CreateNoWindow = true;
    lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardError = true;
    lcmdInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process cmd2 = new Process();
    cmd2.StartInfo = lcmdInfo1;

    var output = new StringBuilder();
    var error = new StringBuilder();

    cmd2.OutputDataReceived += (o, ef) => output.Append(ef.Data);
    cmd2.ErrorDataReceived += (o, ef) => error.Append(ef.Data);
    cmd2.Start();
    cmd2.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmd2.BeginErrorReadLine();
    cmd2.WaitForExit();
    cmd2.Close();
    lresulterr1 = error.ToString();
    lresult1 = output.ToString();
    cmd2.Dispose();

    //sometimes there is an issue with a previously issued command that causes the device status to be 'Unknown'. Wait until the device status is 'device'
    while (!lresult1.Contains("device"))
    { 
        lcmdInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo(" adb.exe ", "get-state");
        lcmdInfo1.CreateNoWindow = true;
        lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardError = true;
        lcmdInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd2 = new Process();
        cmd2.StartInfo = lcmdInfo1;

        output = new StringBuilder();
        error = new StringBuilder();

        cmd2.OutputDataReceived += (o, ef) => output.Append(ef.Data);
        cmd2.ErrorDataReceived += (o, ef) => error.Append(ef.Data);
        cmd2.Start();
        cmd2.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmd2.BeginErrorReadLine();
        cmd2.WaitForExit();
        cmd2.Close();
        lresulterr1 = error.ToString();
        lresult1 = output.ToString();
        cmd2.Dispose();
    }
 //now your device is ready. Go ahead and fire off the shell commands
```